# algebras of algebraic cycles satisfying Hard Lefschetz

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-cycles

June Huh and Botong Wang considired ([arxiv:1609:08808](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08808)) algebras of algebraic classes generated by (all) divisor classes and constructed examples of smooth projective varieties for which this algebra fails to satisfy Hard Lefschetz theorem, in particualar, graded pieces of complementary degree do not have the same dimension.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension $d$ and let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_k$ be irreducible components of a strictly normal crossings divisor. Consider the algebra $A^*$ (graded by codimension) generated by cycle classes of connected components of intersectinos $Y_{i_1} \cap \ldots\cap Y_{i_n}$.

If $A^1$ contains the cycle class of an ample divisor then it follows trivially form Hard Lefschetz theorem that $\mathrm{dim}\, A^n = \mathrm{dim}\, A^{d-n}$. My question is about a degenerate situation when $A^1$ doesn't contain an ample class but $\mathrm{dim}\, A^n = \mathrm{dim}\, A^{d'-n}$ for some $d' < d$. For example, it is the case when there exists a surjective morphism $f: X \to Z$ and $A^*$ is the preimage of $H^{2*}(Z)$.

Is anything known about when the algebra $A$ has the property $\mathrm{dim}\, A^n = \mathrm{dim}\, A^{d'-n}$ for some $d' < d$ otherwise?

I would appreciate any references for any similar questions (i.e. weakenings of Hard Lefschetz property for non-ample classes).

Comment: I'm sure you're aware of this, however de Cataldo and Migliorini study "lef classes": these are classes obtained via pull-back via semi-small maps. They prove (I think?) that a class obtained via pull-back under a proper map satisfies hard Lefschetz if and only if it is "lef". Their paper is <a href="https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006187">here</a>.

Comment: @GeordieWilliamson: yes, I have been pointed in that direction. I was wondering rather about a situation where hard Lefschetz is false for the full cohomology algebra, but is true for a subalgebra. A general result characterising such situations seems very hard to obtain, but I was hoping  to perhaps hear about some non-trivial examples.

Comment: A guess: consider a choice of class in the span in $H^2$ of the $Y_i$'s which is "as ample/positive as possible". If you are lucky, this will be base-point free and give you a map to a projective variety $Z$. Now a standard argument using the decomposition theorem gives that $IH^*(Z)$ will occur as a summand inside $H^*(Z)$, and you will have a slight variant of what you want with $d' = \dim Z$. One might hope that all reasonable examples of the phenomenon you allude to occur in this way ...